# Is this part of the proof really necessary?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Can we immediately say that since $\{a_i\}$ is a cauchy sequence, then it's contained in some closed subset $A_1$ in $M$? Is it necessary to go through mentioning that $\{a_i\}$ is contained by some $B_1$ which may or may not be closed? Sorry if this question is somewhat shallow.

[image]

Comment: Any sequence is contained in some closed set, namely $M$. What you need here is to construct 'small' closed sets, i.e. closed sets with diameters tending to $0$.

Comment: Yes I know M is closed. So can we immediately spawn the closed 'small' subset to existence without saying the sequence is contained in some arbitrary subset $B_1$ which may or may not be closed?

Comment: Why not say there exist a closed and small subset containing sequence immediately? Why go to the trouble of constructing it?

Comment: @TheLastCipher Maybe we could. But the construction would probably be at least as convoluted as this one, while proving that the sets you spawn are closed and that they all contain one another and that their diameter goes to $0$ is still unproven (those things are quite obviously true in this construction). Why exactly are you unhappy with the construction given in the solution?

Comment: My attempt in mind is to immediately use small and closed subsets containing the sequence $\{a_i\}$ and seeing this made me question if I had a logical misstep in assuming that I can argue what I have in mind. Am I missing something logically, by thinking I can immediately spawn those closed and small subsets of $M$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply (b) one has to construct a sequence of sets satisfying (b),
so a descending chain of closed sets with diameters going to zero.

The author could streamline this by defining $A_n$ straight away
as the closure of $\{x_m,x_{m+1},x_{m+2},\ldots\}$. By definition
the $A_n$ are closed, and it's almost immediate that $A_n\supseteq A_{n+1}$.
By the Cauchy condition, given 
$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\ep>0$ then there is $N$ such that
$d(x_n,x_m)<\ep$ when $m$, $n\ge N$. If $u$, $v\in A_N$ then there
are sequences $(m_k)$ and $(n_k)$ of integers
with each $m_k$, $n_k\ge N$ such that $u=\lim_k x_{m_k}$
and $v=\lim_k x_{n_k}$. Then $d(x_{m_k},x_{n_k})<\ep$
and by the continuity of $d$,  $d(u,v)\le\ep$, so that $A_N$
has diameter $\le\ep$. Then $A_{N+1},A_{N+2},\ldots$ must
also have diameter $\le\ep$. Thus the diameters of the $A_n$
tend to zero, and we can apply (b).

Then (b) gives $y\in\bigcap_k A_k$. Then $x_n$, $y\in A_n$
and by a limiting argument as above, $d(x_n,y)\le\textrm{diam}(A_n)$.
Then $y=\lim_n x_n$.